# Why the navbar isn't fixed?

Tags: html, css, navbar

Why my navbar isn't fixed? I mean why it doesn't come down when I scroll down?

This is the code:

```css
nav {
  height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #455868;
  font-size: 11pt;
  font-family: 'PT Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: relative;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #283744;
}
nav ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 600px;
  height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<nav class="clearfix">
  <a href="#" id="pull">Menu</a>
  <ul class="clearfix">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">How-to</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Icons</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Design</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Web 2.0</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Tools</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: You don't have any `fixed`position here .... so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :) hope this will be helped to you

```
  nav {
  height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #455868;
  font-size: 11pt;
  font-family: 'PT Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: fixed;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #283744;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your css to

```
position: fixed;
```

Full code:

```
nav {
  height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #455868;
  font-size: 11pt;
  font-family: 'PT Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: fixed;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #283744;
}
nav ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 600px;
  height: 40px;
}
```

Comment: ty very much! I'm so idiot, I didn't see it. Also If somebody wants the bar to have the margin 0 with top, he needs to put: "top: 0;"